# Create PKCS#7 detached signature

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, keystore, pkcs#7

I've been googling how to do this (in Java) with very little success.
Creating the Signature object is pretty straightforward and so is getting the certificate chain, but how do I create a detached PKCS#7 object with that data?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this here: http://security.stackexchange.com (at least to figure out what that means; then if you don't know *how* to do it, come back and edit this question with the relevant details)

Comment: You're right, Null, sorry. I got an answer there faster than from the technical specification writer.

Comment: A link to that answer would be nice.

Comment: sure :) http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/null-content-digitally-signed-message

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems to be quite a different question, though.

Comment: Null content == detached http://security.stackexchange.com/a/8936/5891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). [Here](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/JCE/PKCS7+Signatures+using+Bouncy+Castle) is the sample of creating PKCS7 signatures with it.

Comment: broken link to example

Comment: yep,  the content has been removed, I suppose, but it is still available in the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ai-proving.com%2F2007%2F09%2F21%2Fpkcs7-signatures-using-bouncy-castle%2F&oq=cache%3Ai-proving.com%2F2007%2F09%2F21%2Fpkcs7-signatures-using-bouncy-castle%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4139j0j4&client=tablet-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8)